# Cassandra: When Read Latency may be NaN while Read Count is non-zero

Tags: cassandra

Several nodes in our Cassandra cluster are reporting 'NaN' for the a certain column family. Here is the output of "nodetool cfstats" for that CF.

```
    Column Family: CFName
    SSTable count: 56
    SSTables in each level: [1, 10, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    Space used (live): 11969490354
    Space used (total): 13943694777
    Number of Keys (estimate): 96397184
    Memtable Columns Count: 3278211
    Memtable Data Size: 195035136
    Memtable Switch Count: 233
    Read Count: 261773771
    Read Latency: NaN ms.
    Write Count: 342708580
    Write Latency: 0.040 ms.
    Pending Tasks: 0
```

My readings on the subject describe this as expected if the number of Read Counts is "0" (zero), which makes sense, given that the latency would be the result of a division by zero. However, in my case, the Read Counts is not zero (in fact we are talking about 261 million reads...).

What could be the root-cause of this? What are other places I should investigate to get more data?

One thing we suspect is timeouts: is it possible for ALL the read to end with timeout which will increment the Read Count metric but not the time metric used by latency?

We are using Cassandra 1.2

Answer (score 0):

The read latency was too small to be counted, this just indicates that the data access was very quick

Comment: Is there any document that justify your argument ?

Can it be also a case of timeout error ?